# My windows 10 taskbar icon width is so wide

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have no idea why the icon width of my windows 10 taskbar became so wide.

[image: IMG:]

I tried "Use small taskbar buttons".

[image: IMG:]

And my "Scale and layout" is 100%, I can't reset it to normal.

[image: IMG:]

Anyone know how to fix it?

Windows10 2004

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update** I've found out how to switch this off!

1. Go to Settings (e.g. [Win]+I), then System, then Tablet; or hit [Win] and type "Tablet settings" to go straight there.
2. Click "Change additional tablet settings"
3. Under "When I'm not in tablet mode", set "Make app icons on the taskbar easier to touch" to off

[image]

---

Original answer

Are you using a 2-in-1 PC in "tent" mode (maybe with an external keyboard and mouse)?

[According to WinCentral](https://thewincentral.com/top-new-features-in-next-windows-10-major-update-2004/), It appears this is a new "feature" in version 2004 (aka 20H1) for 2-in-1 PCs to make it easier to use the touch screen when not using as a "normal" laptop.

I'm afraid I've not found out how to turn it off yet, but it's REALLY annoying!

The only work-around that I can find is to flip your laptop over and use it as a conventional laptop - the icons return to normal size.

Comment: I've raised this on Microsoft Community: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_taskbar/how-to-prevent-icon-widening-in-tent-mode-in/db404fc1-fcee-4760-933a-bc8a19c02e12?tm=1592734545591

Comment: It works, thank you a lot!

Comment: Thank you! This solved my annoyance on my laptop where the "minimum width" of the taskbar buttons was (for some reason) much wider on my laptop than my desktop. The setting above allowed me to enable the taskbar buttons to collapse all the way to just the icon-size! More info (with before/after screenshots) here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/104754-change-width-taskbar-buttons-windows-post2404653.html#post2404653

Answer (score 1):

Open registry editor and navigate to the key  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics` and click `MinWidth` value and change its dword value to 38 (narrow) to anything between 500 (widest) if the key does not exist create it.

Comment: I tried, not work.
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/104754-change-width-taskbar-buttons-windows.html

Comment: This will not work if you have the taskbar set to Always, hide labels to show icons instead of buttons.